# unknown / unauthorized usage of my bandwidth

Tags: networking, manjaro, wireshark

I currently need to work on 3g internet, so i really want to optimize the usage of my slow bandwidth.

But some things are happening against my will, like this one : (use ~50kB/s without asking)

```
GET /manjaro/stable/extra/x86_64/extra.db HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

According to wireshark, i have several :

```
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 45652, Dst Port: 80
```

Is it some sort of `pacman` normal behavior, to run "updates" maybe. (Without asking ???) Or is there something wrong with my os ?

Is there a service / daemon / systemd i am not aware about ?

(next time i will try to capture the name of the process with `netstat`)

Thank you.

Comment: No, it is *not* normal pacman behaviour. Manjaro, however, may run some sort of daemon to check for updates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the culprit. Systemd is actually the one launching periodic commands. (systemd timers)
To list them all : `systemctl list-timers`

Answer (score 1):

Current breed of operating systems including Linux, Windows and MacOS do lot of things in background like downloading updates. Similarly,same is with many applications which keep on downloading updates and new content without user intervention. Unfortunately, there is no quick fix for this problem. It can become tedious to keep a watch on all the software and processes as some of them may become active periodically, like once in day or week at certain hour.

Probably you can consider using a Linux Security Module like `AppArmour`. AppArmor is a Linux Security Module implementation of name-based access controls. AppArmor confines individual programs to a set of listed files and certain posix capabilities. AppArmor network rules provide a flexible profile centric approach to creating a firewall. The network rules are flexible in that they provide both control over creation of sockets, flow of data (packets), and can stand alone or be integrated with the system firewall.

Though I have never used, I believe, with `AppArmour`, you can control the access to Internet on application level. You should give it a try.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor

http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/AppArmor_Core_Policy_Reference#Network_rules